# Testing in Firefox for web app - sloow with caching off

Tags: firefox, asp-classic

I've turned caching off entirely in Firefox, which means each server trip it's pulling down a lot of static JS (jquery includes) that it needn't do.

The problem is-  I don't want the ASP pages to cache.

Is there a solution that lets fox keep the js and only refresh the asp?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1 % %>
```

ought to enforce that your ASP pages aren't cached.  You can then let your browser do its thing with respect to caching the JS files (which to my understanding don't have any no-cache metadata attached.)